# Can you make descriptions constantly visible in cards on Trello?

Tags: trello

Rather than have to click on the description button

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately not.

The titles (which themselves can be quite long) are designed to be permanently visible, while a biggish description could easily take up most of the space in a list, limiting the space available to other cards.

Comment: "It takes up more space" is hardly an good argument against displaying descriptions if I want them. I could only have one or two cards, and space not matter to me. A card that is only title isn't much use. It's really just a card-catalog, Dewey decimal system stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the '[custom fields](https://blog.trello.com/trello-custom-fields)' power-up and define a new field to show on the front of the card

Answer (score 1):

If you feel experimental you can install this extension for Chrome (requires installing in developer mode): https://github.com/alex-ut/trello-full-descriptions.

Works like a charm (as of July 2017)

Comment: Wanted to note that this solution can be used on Firefox also: Install [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) and add Tampermonkey script with [content from extension](https://github.com/alex-ut/trello-full-descriptions/blob/master/full-descriptions.js).